# Tree Data Structure in HashMap

Tags: java, json, data-structures, tree, hashmap

I'm trying to create a tree structure based on a result set I get from a query. The below block of code works only if the result set has two columns. The first column is the parent and the second column is the child. Problem I'm running into is trying to re-engineer this so that it can incorporate multiple different levels (each column representing a level). Only way for me to do it now is to duplicate the code, check the number of levels and hard-coding to add in a new level. I'm processing the result set by row then column. (e.g. get the first row, then get the first column and store that value.)

Any idea on how I can re-engineer this functionality to be flexible on the number of levels it can go? Ultimately, the root gets passed into a HashTable and processed to a JSON file. FYI, I'm doing the JSON formatting in the second part of the code by traversing through the HashMap and formatting it to fit what I need for the JSON.

```
    HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> level1TwoColumn = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

    Object[] listElementCalcColumnNumber = list.get(0);

    Hashtable allHash = new Hashtable();

        //this will store all of the values in a hashmap and hashset
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            Object[] listElement = list.get(i);

            //the reason we added ""+ between (String) and listElement is because listElement can be something other than a String (e.g. double, integer, etc)
            //by adding "" to it, it becomes a String value automatically so then we can cast double/integer/etc into a String
            String currentLevel1 = (String) ""+listElement[0];
            currentLevel1 = currentLevel1.replace("\"", "");
            //this prevents variables from duplicating. if the new element does not exist in hashmap, a new record in the hashmap will be created.
            if((level1TwoColumn.get(currentLevel1) = null)){
                HashSet<String> level2 = new HashSet<String>();

                level1TwoColumn.put(currentLevel1, level2);
            }

            //stores all of the lowest level into a hashset because they're all going to be unique. no need to check to see if they exist in the hashset.
            String currentLevel2 = (String) ""+listElement[1];
            currentLevel2 = currentLevel2.replace("\"", "");

            level1TwoColumn.get(currentLevel1).add(currentLevel2);
        }

        HashSet completeTree = new HashSet();

        //now that the structure of the data is complete. iterate through level1 to get and store keys as values and "name" as key
        for(String key1 : level1TwoColumn.keySet()){
            HashSet levelOneSet = new HashSet();

            HashMap levelOne = new HashMap();

            levelOne.put("name", key1);
            levelOneSet.add(levelOne);

            //this for-statement does the same thing as previous for-statement; stores the unique values and give them "name" and then put them in hashset and give the set a "children" key
            for(String key2 : level1TwoColumn.get(key1)){
                HashSet levelTwoSet = new HashSet();

                HashMap levelTwo = new HashMap();
                levelTwo.put("name", key2);
                levelTwoSet.add(levelTwo);

                levelOne.put("children", levelTwoSet);
            }

            //once it loops through once, all level 2 items will be stored under a unique level 1. then it gets added into our dendrogram one by one until all level 1 elements are added.
            completeTree.add(levelOne);
        }

        //this is assigning what our first node is, which is "VA"
        allHash.put("name", "VA");
        //put everything under "VA" node
        allHash.put("children", completeTree);
```

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused as to what your problem is.  A HashMap is one "branch junction" of a tree, and one can easily construct a tree of arbitrary complexity recursively using HashMaps.  And the HashMap maps naturally to JSON "objects" -- if you use the right JSON kit then no conversions/hand-holding is required -- just pass the root to the JSON kit and say "serialize".

Comment: Apologize if it was confusing. My problem is being able to keep building on the HashMap dynamically. Currently, I'm setting it to be HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> level1TwoColumn. So that means it can only be two levels deep. I'm trying to re-engineer my code so that it keeps building branches depending on the number of columns the users defines.

Comment: The only way to do it is to use a `Map<String, Object>` then use lots of ugly casts. It's best to use a proper data structure.

Comment: Forget about trying to keep the generic junk happy.  You need to make the HashMap be `<String, Object>` anyway, since "leaves" will not be HashMaps.  Get in bed with casts and `instanceof`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Since when are casts "ugly"?

Comment: @HotLicks they're generally not. But when you have a large nested structure and you're trying to navigate it then it gets fairly hairy. Plus you very quickly lose any semblance of type safety.

Comment: We're talking JSON here.  You have to accept that an entity can be array, object, number, string, bool, or null.  If you wish you can use one of the JSON kits that wraps Maps and Lists with their own objects, to hide the casts (behind "getObjet", "getArray", "getString", etc), but it doesn't really change anything.  The real world isn't type-safe.

Comment: @BoristheSpider is there a proper data structure you're thinking of? I've thought about using Map<String, Object> and casting to get it right. Issue here is the logic to keep adding on different levels. Is there a way to make Map<String, Object> to Map<String, Map<Object>>. Maybe I'm not thinking this through correctly.

Comment: @HotLicks agreed. In the case where you are processing random JSON then this is the case. I would argue, however, that when you are processing data you almost certainly know the structure of that data. You can create classes to contain that data and then marshall your data into that structure.

Comment: I've found that very often the simplest, clearest way to represent the data is as a tree of Maps and Lists.